# Why isn't variance considered a bigger deal than bias?

Tags: variance, bias

In statistical literature, people say:

> Let's avoid making a **biased estimator**, that will mess things up!

Why not avoid also having a varianced estimator? They should be treated the same.

Comment: Perhaps you would enjoy Maurice Kendalls' Hiawatha poem. http://www.columbia.edu/~to166/hiawatha.html

Comment: What do you mean by "varianced estimator"?

Comment: An estimator with too much variance

Comment: quick answer: if you have data with noise, often you *can* have an unbiased estimator. Considered in isolation, unbiased is considered better than unbiased. But you can almost never have an estimator with no variance (and if you can, you don't need statistics)! Hence why they are not treated exactly the same.

Comment: It would be interesting to know who these people are. I know many who care about variance, perhaps even more than bias (maximum likelihood is often biased but as. effficient).

Answer (score 2):

People do care about reducing both the bias and variance error when making a statistical model, but there is a [bias-variance tradeoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff). In supervised learning, if you shoot for low bias, you can *overfit* your model which leads to high variance. Alternatively if you shoot for low variance, you can *underfit* your model and get high bias.

Comment: Not in machine learning necessarily. Just in general stats - "aim for an unbiased estimator".  I don't understand why variance is treated with the same scrutiny.

Answer (score 1):

Variance is also treated with the same scrutiny. Generally, in practice, unbiased estimators are used, that are also UMVUE (uniformly minimum-variance unbiased estimators). This is not discussed in modern literature because there is a lot of existing research about UMVUEs for different parameters of different distributions.

In addition, often the word 'bias' is also introduced when talking about the quality of the sample. If the sample obtained in not representative of the population, you will get biased results. This is also a bias that is generally discussed in literature.

Comment: UMVUE gives priority to bias and treats variance as secondary. I wonder if the order could be reversed: first minimize the variance, then see if there are competing estimators that give the same variance but have different biases and use the one with the lowest bias.

Comment: That would be difficult, since I can always construct a deterministic estimator, whose variance is going to be 0. Minimizing the bias then would require the estimator to be the parameter itself.

Comment: @Greenparker: +1 to this. Minimizing the variance, unless we already have a *ad hoc* lower bound, of a point estimate $T$ will let $E[T-E[T]]^2=0$ so that $T=E[T]$. Then minimizing bias will simply mean let $T$ be whatever we are estimating.